# XCompose with GTK results in strange behavior for own mapping

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, compose-key

I had problems using my own `~/.XCompose` in GTK Apps such as Thunderbird or Signal-Desktop. After adding these lines to `~/.profile` it (almost) worked.

```
# XCompose
export QT_IM_MODULE="xim"
export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"
```

Here are two examples which differ in behavior when used:

```
<Multi_key> <o> <o> : "ö"
<Multi_key> <s> <s> : "ß"
```

Both combination are already setup in `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`. The latter one is added by default with the same mapping (`ss -> ß`). While the first one is mapped (by default and should be overwritten) to the degree symbol `°`.

When I am entering the latter combination "ß" appears as it's supposed to be. But the first combination yields a strange result which is hard to explain. After entering the combination a small underscore/bar appears below the letter. When I enter another letter it is inserted before the "ö". For e.g.:

```
INPUT: <Multi_key> <o> <o>
OUTPUT:  ö # with a bar underneath

INPUT: m
OUTPUT: mö # inserted in front??
```

In comparison (to illustrate this strange bug a little better):

```
INPUT: <Multi_key> <s> <s>
OUTPUT:  ß 

INPUT: m
OUTPUT: ßm
```

Both results are the same in GTK Apps and for e.g. bash shell.
OS Information:

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
```

Answer (score 0):

There were duplicated lines in the `~/.XCompose` file I used which resulted in this strange behavior. Now, having only unique definitions and removed the redundant defintions, everything works.

Content of `~/.profile`:

```
...
export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"
```